# Shabbat candles penalty when traveling

Tags: shabbat, candle-lighting

Regarding the [knas](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9648/33217) of women lighting multiple shabbat candles — must she light all those extra candles for the rest of her life?

My main question is concerning when traveling, must she light all the candles?

What about if it's a burden on the host to prepare numerous candles. Or will the two suffice?

Comment: The burden is never on the host. She is obligated to provide her own candles.

Comment: Two will suffice, especially when travelling.